# "flutter web is currently not supported"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a website in flutter web

When I use the command

```
webdev serve
```

Everything works, but when I use the command

```
flutter build web
```

I get this error:

```
Downloading Web SDK...                                              1,6s
"build web" is not currently supported.
```

This is my flutter version

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.15 xxxx, locale xxx)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.40.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced the same issue.

Follow the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)

In my case, I missed to execute the following command

```
> flutter config --enable-web
```

Also, ensure that you are in the 'Dev' channel

```
flutter channel dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter 1.9 has early support for web application and the message seems to say you're not using a channel which has the web development
Did you change the channel to be able to build your web application: `flutter channel dev`, upgrade flutter, enable web in the configuration?

I don't use `webdev serve` but `flutter run -d chrome`

When running `flutter doctor -v`, you should have something like:

`[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.15-pre.272, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.10.15-pre.272 at /Users/erictaix/development/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 5bc7fb6835 (13 days ago), 2019-10-27 21:25:13 -0700
    • Engine revision 3ebf006904
    • Dart version 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.8.2 6354b0b97d)
...
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • macOS      • macOS      • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 78.0.3904.97
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools`

Note that flutter use `master` channel on my computer (`dev` should work) and in connected devices, you can see Chrome and Web Server.

My version is `1.10` because as mentioned, I use the channel `master` which is not stable at all. But with `dev` channel it should work. Please refer to the documentation for up-to-date instructions: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web